Defining a parameterized property in Lean 4
I'm essentially messing around with Lean 4, and I have a very simple encoding of arithmetic terms:
inductive Term where
| Num : Nat -> Term
| Plus : Term -> Term -> Term
| Mul : Term -> Term -> Term
deriving Repr

open Term

I decided to try to prove that all terms with no addition and at least one zero evaluate to zero, and I ran into what I think might be just a simple syntactic problem. Specifically, I want to define the property has_no_adds. This is what I came up with:
inductive has_no_addition Term where
| noadd_is_num :  (n : Nat ) -> has_no_addition (Num n)

that is: has_no_addition is of type Term -> Type (okay, I wish it was Term -> Prop, but I think that's a different question), a type that's parameterized by terms, and one way to prove that a term has no addition is to state that it's just a number. That is, (noadd_is_num 4) is a proof that the term (Num 4) has no addition in it.
I'm getting the error
inductive datatype parameter mismatch
  Num n
expected
  Term

Oh! Got it. Okay, I'll post anyway and then the answer, just in case this is useful to someone else....

You do realize your definition if has_no_addition is not complete? Also, you could  put it in Prop, why wouldn't you? Let me know if you'd like to see the relevant definitions of has_no_addition and has_zero.

complete: yes, it definitely isn't, I was just getting started. I've now added a complete definition for has_no_addition. And yes, it can certainly be a Prop. Let me know if I misunderstood you!

Silly me, the correct syntax is
inductive has_no_addition : Term -> Prop where
| noadd_is_num :  (n : Nat ) -> has_no_addition (Num n)

It seems obvious now.... but it wasn't obvious five minutes ago. Hope this is useful to someone else!
EDIT: Per Andrej Bauer's instructive comment above, I will paste a complete example with a more complete definition of has_no_addition, just in case it's helpful!
inductive Term where
| Num : Nat -> Term
| Plus : Term -> Term -> Term
| Mul : Term -> Term -> Term
deriving Repr

open Term

inductive has_no_addition : Term -> Prop where
| noadd_num (n : Nat ) : has_no_addition (Num n)
| noadd_mul {t1 t2 : Term} (ht1 : has_no_addition t1) (ht2 : has_no_addition t2) : has_no_addition (Mul t1 t2)
open has_no_addition

theorem ex1 : has_no_addition (Num 4) :=
  noadd_num 4

theorem ex2 : has_no_addition (Mul (Num 3) (Num 4)) :=
  noadd_mul (noadd_num 3) (noadd_num 4)

